# How can I get Control Panel's Add/Remove programs list?

Tags: windows, wmi

Ho can I obtain/export the Windows Control Panel Add/Remove programs list using WMI or VB script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wmic product` on the local machine. You can also use `wmic /NODE:computername get product` on remote machines. It will take a while.

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't return the list from Control's Panel Add/Remove. It returns some installed programs, probably, the ones installed using windows installer.

Comment: It is going to be helpful anyway